# Why Angular Material is responsive and AngularJS Material isn't?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-material

I'm trying to choose a framework for an application of mine and I stumbled across [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) and [AngularJS Material](https://material.angularjs.org). I understand that both are from Google (correct me if I'm wrong) but basically are both doing more or less the same, rendering components in a HTML page, what I don't get (and searching Google around is not very efficient due to confusion on similar name) why Angular material is not responsive and AngularJS Material is? Which one I should choose in order to make my app responsive? Or... how would I get an Angular Material app responsive?

Answer (score 2):

Just because the website documenting the library is not responsive it does not mean the library itself is not responsive either. In fact, both are responsive, but obviously whether your app is going to be responsive or not, that depends mainly on you, not just the library.

As to which one you should choose, that should be your main question. AngularJS Material is for AngularJS (v1.x) and Angular Material is for Angular (v2+).

I agree with you that the naming is confusing, but you should not concern yourself with that. Pick a framework first, not the library. Picking a library first would be like choosing a paint, going home and wondering which rooms you can paint with that color. It might be the case that the paint is very universal and can by applied to all your walls in all your rooms. But it might be the case that the color is very specific and it would not look good in either of your rooms.

Answer (score 1):

You should use angularjs material because responsiveness comes as a built in since it is a directive based approach applying any CSS will be quite complicated in that.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, AngularJS Material is still work in progress. (A lot of features are still being added). A good reason to use it (just mentioning as eg.) Angular-data-table is no longer supported in 1.x and development is stopped on it, but more work is being put into md-data-table which is the material design version of the same and offers a heck lot of features.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-data-table

Answer (score 1):

For your Angular 2 and Angular 4 apps you can use

- https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

You can see on this demo how it is implemente a responsive layout.

- https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/responsive

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Why Angular material is not responsive and AngularJS Material is?

They both are. AngularJS Material is responsive through its `layout component`. Angular Material is responsive through [Angular Flex-Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

> Which one I should choose in order to make my app responsive?

Angular Flex-Layout is much more powerful than AngularJS Material's `layout`. And if you learn it once, you can use it in all your Angular 2+ apps, not just Angular Material

> Or..how would I get an Angular Material app responsive?

As already mentioned with [Angular Flex-Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout). No need for an additional grid like Bootstrap.